# How to set time delay for displaying the alertview from one after another From an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, alertview

How to set time delay for displaying the alertview from one after another From an array? I have 5 alertview in an array.. Each alertview will Display after Some time duration.

```
     for (NSDictionary *temp in [RMUserDefaults userDetails].SharedFolders)
        {
          NSString *name = temp[@"Name"];          
          alert1= [[CustomUIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"message" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message.", name] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:nil]]; 
          [alert1 show];
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem when you are using this code? Please explain more so i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ......

```
-(void)test{
    [self showAlertWithIndex:0];
}

-(void)showAlertWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSArray * arr = [RMUserDefaults userDetails].SharedFolders;
    NSString *name = arr[index][@"Name"];
    alert1= [[CustomUIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"message" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message.", name] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:nil]];
    alert1.tag = index;
    [alert1 show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) withObject:alert1 afterDelay:2.0f];
    // set delay in above line
}

-(void)dismissAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    NSInteger index = alert.tag+1;

    NSArray * arr = [RMUserDefaults userDetails].SharedFolders;
    if (index < arr.count)
    {
        [self showAlertWithIndex:index];
    }
}
```

EDIT :

You will need to write following code in your alertview delegate

```
    NSInteger index = alert.tag+1;

    NSArray * arr = [CustomUIAlertView userDetails].SharedFolders;
    if (index < arr.count)
    {
        [self showAlertWithIndex:index];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch_after

```
int i = 1;

for (NSDictionary *temp in [RMUserDefaults userDetails].SharedFolders) {
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, i * delaySeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        NSString *name = temp[@"Name"]; 
        alert1= [[CustomUIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"message" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message.", name] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:nil]];
        [alert1 show];
    });

    i++;

}
```